# how to set the TIFF image resolution with Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I use the following scripts to set the resolution of a tiff image:

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open('abc.bmp')
im.info
im=im.convert('1')
im.info
im.save('abc.tif')
```

As I can clearly see that the resolution of the image is ('dpi': (300, 300)), I assume that the output TIFF image should have the resolution 300 DPI. However, the output resolution is undefined when I read the head file information of the TIFF File.  Any ideas on setting the resolution? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've use ImageMagick's `identify` program to read the file meta-data. My source file was the [venerable Lena image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) for which:

```
$ identify -verbose lena.jpg
…
Resolution: 72x72
…
```

where the resolution is contained in the JFIF block. PIL† does not appear to translate this JFIF block in Image.open:

```
>>> im = Image.open('lena.jpg')
>>> im.info 
{'exif': b'Exif\x00\x00II*\x00\x08…',
 'jfif': 257,
 'jfif_density': (1, 1),
 'jfif_unit': 0,
 'jfif_version': (1, 1)}
```

However, you can specify resolution for TIFF output

```
>>> im.save('lena.tiff', dpi=(300, 300))
>>> lena = Image.open('lena.tiff')
>>> lena.info
{'compression': 'raw', 'dpi': (300.0, 300.0)}
```

and `identify` agrees

```
$ identify -verbose lena.tiff
…
  Resolution: 300x300
…
```

---

#### †A note on the apparent death of PIL

As far as I can tell, the [last release of PIL was in 2009](http://pythonware.com/products/pil/) which was supplanted by the [Pillow Project](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) which appears to be in [active development](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow). Unfortunately, Pillow didn't change the package name, so it if you write:

```
import PIL
```

or

```
from PIL import Image
```

you have know way of knowing which library you are working with except by

```
>>> PIL.PILLOW_VERSION
```

which should yield a NameError under PIL but a version number ('2.9.0' is latest release) under Pillow.

If you are using PIL, not Pillow, I have no idea if the answer above will work for you, and I've hit the limit as to how much PIL-ish code I want to read today.

Comment: PIL deserves to die. I haven't tried Pillow yet, but I'm curious to know if they've fixed the bugs I identified in the resizing code.